rxjs how i can force one stream wait to another one and then continue
Problem:
I’m using Angular and have two streams in my component:
First stream:
Makes an HTTP request to fetch some data.
After the data is fetched, I need to initialize two valueChanges for two controls.
Every time a user changes these controls, I trigger logic based on the data fetched from the HTTP request.
Second stream:
Makes another HTTP request to fetch some data.
This data is used to patch values to my entire formGroup.
I want to ensure that this patch happens only after the first stream completes, because I need to initialize the valueChanges first.
Requirements:
Sequence of events:
The first HTTP request must complete before initializing the valueChanges for the controls.
The second HTTP request should only fire after the first HTTP request completes and the form controls are initialized.
Any changes made by the user to the controls (from the first stream) should trigger the associated logic, but I want to ignore the second stream, as it only runs during the initialization phase.
Challenges:
I need to ensure the second HTTP request for patching values happens only once and does not trigger further, even when the user interacts with the form controls after the initial setup.
The second stream should be independent of the user’s changes to the form controls.
How can I manage the flow of these streams to meet these requirements?
What I’ve Tried:
First Stream:
I start with an observable from the HTTP request (I use a store, but that’s not important here).
I use switchMap to handle the data, then initialize the valueChanges for two controls, and apply some logic with tap. After that, I merge them together and return the result.
This part works fine, but I face challenges with the second stream.
Second Stream:
When I try to combine the streams, I run into issues.
Here are some approaches I considered and why they didn’t work for my scenario:
Using switchMap: If I start with the first stream and then switchMap to the second, the problem is that any change to the first stream will re-trigger the second, which I don’t want. I need to make sure the second stream fires only once during the initialization phase.
Using concatMap: This approach doesn’t work for me because it waits for the second stream to complete before triggering the first stream. This means the user’s valueChanges on the first stream won’t trigger because the second stream is waiting to complete first.
Using mergeMap: This doesn't work either because it doesn’t respect the order of events. It doesn’t wait for the first stream to finish before the second one starts, which isn’t what I need.
What I Need:
I need to wait for the first HTTP request to complete, initialize the form controls, and then trigger the second stream to patch the form values.
The second stream should only run once when the component is initialized, not every time the user changes a value on the form controls.
The first stream needs to handle any changes to the form controls immediately and execute the logic associated with those changes.
I’ve created a StackBlitz example to demonstrate the issue. As you can see, I expect the order to be:

stream1$

stream2$



You are not demonstrating anything with your stackblitz demo, you've only created 2 observables, then what? what's the form? what are the form controls attach to the form? what values changes should be listen to? etc...

hello @Andres2142 , i have two fromControls attach to two input field and i want to listen  the changed and make some logic after every changed, but i need to get some data first to use inside the logic that run on every changed. this is in my demo i dont understand waht i missing. thx for the response.

You have two different desires, but you want to do them together, which is not possible. This is my suggested method:
  fb = inject(FormBuilder);
  fg = this.fb.group({
    formControl1: new FormControl(),
    formControl2: new FormControl(),
  });
  stream1$ = of([1, 2, 3, 4]).pipe(delay(2000));
  stream2$ = of([1, 2, 3, 4]).pipe(delay(1000), tap());

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.inititialize();
  }

  inititialize(): void {
    this.stream1$.pipe(
      take(1),
      tap((x) => {
        this.changeForm(x);
      }),
      switchMap((x) => this.stream2$)
    );
    this.subscribeToChanges();
  }

  changeForm(x: any): void {
    this.fg.patchValue(x);
    // or any job you need
  }

  subscribeToChanges(): void {
    this.fg.events
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        switchMap(() => this.stream1$)
      )
      .subscribe((x) => {
        this.changeForm(x);
      });
  }


hello @Mojtaba , why do you think that my desires its not possible? i think its something very common i just want to active listeners for the value changed only when some data arrived and i have another stream that update my formGroup and i want it to fire after my listeners work, why its so bad approach?. thx for the response.

obviously you have two desire. initialization and modification
